# Cocoa: Triggering NSWindow makeKeyAndOrderFront instance method from another class

Tags: objective-c, cocoa

*This is **not** about the appearance of the window* - or - about passing arguments around, but being able to call the **[makeKeyAndOrderFront](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/appkit/nswindow/1419208-makekeyandorderfront?language=objc)** instance method through code (IB Receiver actions work fine, as do methods within the window implementation block), from ***another*** class.

I understand this should be trivial, and that I am not grasping the messaging structure properly or doing my declarations properly, but I've started to go around in circles, and the many questions on SO and other blogs and forums have not been close enough to this exact fashion to help me click to where I'm going wrong.

While I've tried a number of things, this (although incorrect) is probably the attempt that is the most obvious at showing what I am ***trying*** to do:

**NSWindow SubClass**

```
@interface hTaskWindow
- (id)initWithContentRect:// etc...

- (IBAction)hWindowActivate:(id)sender;

// ...
@end 
@implementation hTaskWindow

- (id)initWithContentRect:(NSRect)contentRect styleMask:(unsigned int)aStyle backing:(NSBackingStoreType)bufferingType defer:(BOOL)flag {

    self = [super initWithContentRect:contentRect styleMask:NSFullSizeContentViewWindowMask backing:NSBackingStoreBuffered defer:NO];

    [self setTitle:titlename];
    [self setStyleMask:[self styleMask] | //


// 
// Plus a bunch  
// of style
// customisations here
//
// "Visible at launch" is Unticked on this Window.
// 
//

-(void)activateDebugWindow {   //       <---------  I just want to call this from anywhere!
    NSLog(@"This works fine when triggered from IB button");
    [self makeKeyAndOrderFront:self];
}

-(IBAction)hWindowActivate:(id)sender { 
    [self activateDebugWindow]; 
}
@end
```

**NSObject SubClass:**

```
@interface AppController : NSObject {
}
@end

@implementation AppController

// whole bunch of working stuff ...
    NSLog(@"This logs fine when I press my global hotkey");

    hTaskWindow *hwindow;                                      // Nothing happens
    [hwindow makeKeyAndOrderFront:(hwindow)];                  // Here at all

    NSLog(@"This logs fine when I press my global hotkey");
// whole bunch of working stuff ...
@end
```

**The goal is to open hTaskWindow Programmatically from another class**

- I have a Menu Shortcut with a hotkey, connected directly to the receiver action `makeKeyAndOrderFront` on the Window Controller which **opens the window**
- I have an `NSButton` connected to `hWindowActivate` which also **opens the window**
- I have a global hotkey which successfully records an entry in **NSLog**

But what I am trying to do is have my global hotkey method activate the function which opens the window in the other class.

The currently un-necessary `-(void)activateDebugWindow` called from the IBAction was just to try set up a point where both the XIB **and** a piece of code could bring open the same window.

Comment: Do you want to call `makeKeyAndOrderFront` on an existing window or do you want to create a new window?

Comment: @Willeke call `makeKeyAndOrderFront` on an existing window.  The init is done, I will revise code to include some more.

Comment: @Willeke you can see more of the window code now.  If i add the line `[self makeKeyAndOrderFront:NULL];` in the customisations then the window launches when the app starts.  Currently, the `activateDebugWindow` method works to open the window, but only if called using the interface builder connections from the menu item, or a button.

Comment: Which object is the owner of the window?

Comment: @Willeke the window controller I thought, which is not subclassed

Comment: Which object is the owner of the window controller?

Comment: @Willeke it looks to me like an NSDocument subclass owns the windowcontroller.  Is that possible?  There are two windows in the one xib file, first window is connected to files owner and window outlet, second window just has hTaskWindow as its class.

Comment: The identifier of the window returned when opening it from the view menu or a button, is NS700 (as entered into IB).  (null) is returned from the same method when trying to run it programmatically

Comment: Do you have a `hTaskWindow` for each document or one `hTaskWindow` for the app? And what is `AppController`?

Comment: @Willeke there's only one hTaskWindow for the app.  I can see cleaner setups for this app, but I'd like to get some deeper understanding of the internal structures and experience with solving problems like this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`hTaskWindow` should be in the xib of the app. Add an outlet in the app delegate to connect to `hTaskWindow`. `hWindowActivate` should be in the app delegate. You can activate the window from everywhere with `[[NSApp delegate] hWindowActivate:sender]`.

```
-(IBAction)hWindowActivate:(id)sender { 
    [self.hTaskWindow makeKeyAndOrderFront:sender];
}
```

Connect menu items and buttons in IB to the app delegate or first responder and `hWindowActivate:`.

Answer (score 1):

You will have to load the window you want to display before calling `makeKeyAndOrderFront:` on it. It is done via a NSWindowController.

Change these lines

```
hTaskWindow *hwindow;
[hwindow makeKeyAndOrderFront:(hwindow)];
```

To

```
hTaskWindow *hwindow = [[hTaskWindow alloc] init]; // initialize window here
NSWindowController *windowController = [[NSWindowController alloc] initWithWindow:hwindow];
[windowController.window makeKeyAndOrderFront:self];
```

If your window is loaded from a .xib file, you should use the `initWithWindowNibName:` method to initialize the window controller.

Comment: Thanks for the help, now I have actually tried something very similar to this (and now this) and I get this same result - `use of undeclared identifier 'self'`

Comment: This is an unusual error which might only happen if you have syntax errors.